# Copy project build output and any files marked as 'Build Action: Content' to directory

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-process

The goal is to take a .NET Visual Studio project and create a folder containing the bin folder and any files marked as 'Build Action: Content', while preserving the folder structure. The solution contains various projects types, so the solution cannot be specific to any particular project type.

I suppose it would need to be a command line tool so it could be run as post-build step to be perfect, but any ideas welcome.

Feels like there might be a tool out there that would do this. I am reading around [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) but wonder if it might be overkill.

I realise I might need to write a console app or something here and am okay with that. I am interested in any and all ideas in terms or solutions/tools/frameworks.

Comment: For ASP.Net projects that is exactly what `Publish` target does. What kind of project do you have?

Comment: Yes, it's a .NET project, but a mixture of various project types, some which don't have this option. I'll edit to make this clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Build properties  for a file have also settings "Copy To Output Directory" set it to "copy if newer" and you all set.
How it looks like in csproj:

```
<Content Include="TextFile1.txt">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

For preserving folder structure without any additional coding i whould recoment to have a project for each folder in your structure and set build output for them accordingly to your structure.

Comment: I'm okay with additional coding, I do realise this is not necessarily a trivial ask. I can write the console app I call from the post build step etc, but am interested in what people might use to go about this. Will add to the question actually.